# NoMethodError in EventsController#index | undefined method `has_reputation' for [rails4]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

i am new to rails - so any help will be much appreciated. i am currently using the GEM 'twitter/activerecord-reputation-system' and following the rails tutorial #364 on rails cast.

1. i am unsure why i am getting the error as i thought the has_reputation method should be already automatically defined within the GEM
2. I have also restarted my console/terminal but still get the same error. Any help will be much appreciated

**my error:** #undefined method `has_reputation' for #

```
Started GET "/events" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-08-21 10:37:36 +0100
Processing by EventsController#index as HTML
  User Load (1.1ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."id" = 1  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 9ms

NoMethodError (undefined method `has_reputation' for #<Class:0x007f87cb9efed0>):
  app/models/event.rb:5:in `<class:Event>'
  app/models/event.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
  app/controllers/events_controller.rb:8:in `index'


  Rendered /Users/ARTLoe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/actionpack-4.1.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_source.erb (0.6ms)
  Rendered /Users/ARTLoe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/actionpack-4.1.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb (1.2ms)
  Rendered /Users/ARTLoe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/actionpack-4.1.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.html.erb (0.9ms)
  Rendered /Users/ARTLoe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/actionpack-4.1.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.erb within rescues/layout (11.9ms)
```

**models**

```
#event model
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :comments, as: :commentable

  has_reputation :votes, source: :user, aggregated_by: :sum

  validates :city, :date, :description, :name, :price, :time, presence: true
  validates :price, numericality: {greater_than_or_equal_to: 0.01}
  validates :name, length: { minimum: 5 }
  validates :name, length: { maximum: 22 }
  validates :user_id, presence: true
end

#user model
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  has_many :events, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :comments, as: :commentable, dependent: :destroy

  has_many :relationships, foreign_key: "follower_id", dependent: :destroy
  has_many :followed_users, through: :relationships, source: :followed

  has_many :reverse_relationships, foreign_key: "followed_id", class_name: "Relationship", dependent: :destroy
  has_many :followers, through: :reverse_relationships, source: :follower

  validates_presence_of :firstname, :lastname
end
```

**route**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  devise_for :users
  get '/about', to: 'static_pages#about'
  get '/help', to: 'static_pages#help'
  get '/terms', to: 'static_pages#terms'
  get '/policy', to: 'static_pages#policy'
  get '/contact', to: 'static_pages#contact'
  get '/blabber', to: 'static_pages#blabber_public'

  resources :users do
    member do
      get :following, :followers
    end
  end

  resources :events do 
    resources :comments, only: [:create, :destroy]
    member { post :vote }
  end

  root to: 'home#index', as: 'home'

  resources :relationships, only: [:create, :destroy]
end
```

**schema**

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20140820114256) do

  # These are extensions that must be enabled in order to support this database
  enable_extension "plpgsql"

  create_table "comments", force: true do |t|
    t.text     "content"
    t.integer  "commentable_id"
    t.string   "commentable_type"
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  add_index "comments", ["commentable_id", "commentable_type"], name: "index_comments_on_commentable_id_and_commentable_type", using: :btree

  create_table "events", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.text     "description"
    t.date     "date"
    t.time     "time"
    t.text     "city"
    t.decimal  "price",       precision: 8, scale: 2
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.integer  "user_id"
  end

  create_table "relationships", force: true do |t|
    t.integer  "follower_id"
    t.integer  "followed_id"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  add_index "relationships", ["followed_id"], name: "index_relationships_on_followed_id", using: :btree
  add_index "relationships", ["follower_id", "followed_id"], name: "index_relationships_on_follower_id_and_followed_id", unique: true, using: :btree
  add_index "relationships", ["follower_id"], name: "index_relationships_on_follower_id", using: :btree

  create_table "rs_evaluations", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "reputation_name"
    t.integer  "source_id"
    t.string   "source_type"
    t.integer  "target_id"
    t.string   "target_type"
    t.float    "value",           default: 0.0
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  add_index "rs_evaluations", ["reputation_name"], name: "index_rs_evaluations_on_reputation_name", using: :btree
  add_index "rs_evaluations", ["source_id", "source_type"], name: "index_rs_evaluations_on_source_id_and_source_type", using: :btree
  add_index "rs_evaluations", ["target_id", "target_type"], name: "index_rs_evaluations_on_target_id_and_target_type", using: :btree

  create_table "rs_reputation_messages", force: true do |t|
    t.integer  "sender_id"
    t.string   "sender_type"
    t.integer  "receiver_id"
    t.float    "weight",      default: 1.0
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  add_index "rs_reputation_messages", ["receiver_id"], name: "index_rs_reputation_messages_on_receiver_id", using: :btree
  add_index "rs_reputation_messages", ["sender_id", "sender_type"], name: "index_rs_reputation_messages_on_sender_id_and_sender_type", using: :btree

  create_table "rs_reputations", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "reputation_name"
    t.float    "value",           default: 0.0
    t.string   "aggregated_by"
    t.integer  "target_id"
    t.string   "target_type"
    t.boolean  "active",          default: true
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  add_index "rs_reputations", ["reputation_name"], name: "index_rs_reputations_on_reputation_name", using: :btree
  add_index "rs_reputations", ["target_id", "target_type"], name: "index_rs_reputations_on_target_id_and_target_type", using: :btree

  create_table "users", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "email",                  default: "", null: false
    t.string   "encrypted_password",     default: "", null: false
    t.string   "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.integer  "sign_in_count",          default: 0,  null: false
    t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
    t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
    t.string   "current_sign_in_ip"
    t.string   "last_sign_in_ip"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.string   "firstname"
    t.string   "lastname"
    t.date     "dob"
    t.string   "gender"
    t.text     "description"
    t.string   "role"
  end

  add_index "users", ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true, using: :btree
  add_index "users", ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true, using: :btree

end
```

**events_controller**

```
class EventsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_event, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_filter :authenticate_user!

  def index
    @events = Event.order(:date)
    # @events = current_user.events | displays only events by current user
  end

  def show
    @commentable = @event
    @comments = @commentable.comments
    @comment = Comment.new
  end

  def new
    @event = Event.new
  end

  def edit
  end

  def create
    @event = Event.new(event_params)
    @event.user = current_user

    respond_to do |format|
      if @event.save
        format.html { redirect_to @event, notice: 'Event was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @event }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @event.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /events/1
  # PATCH/PUT /events/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @event.update(event_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @event, notice: 'Event was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @event }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @event.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @event.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to events_url, notice: 'Event was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  def vote
    value = params[:type] == "up" ? 1 : -1
    @event = Event.find(params[:id])
    @event.add_or_update_evaluation(:votes, value, current_user)
    redirect_to :back, notice: "Thank you for voting"
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_event
      @event = Event.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def event_params
      params.require(:event).permit(:name, :description, :date, :time, :city, :price, :user_id)
    end
end
```

Gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'


# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.1.1'
# Use postgresql as the database for Active Record
gem 'pg'
gem 'ancestry'
gem 'acts_as_votable'
gem 'acts_as_list'
gem 'acts_as_commentable', '3.0.1'
gem 'best_in_place'
gem 'carrierwave', '=0.9.0'
gem 'cancan'
gem 'devise'
gem 'fancybox-rails'
gem 'font-awesome-rails'
gem 'jquery-ui-rails'
gem 'kaminari'
gem 'letter_opener'
gem 'ransack'
# gem 'rmagick'
gem 'thumbs_up'
gem 'simple_form'
gem 'activerecord-reputation-system', github: 'NARKOZ/activerecord-reputation-system'
gem 'quiet_assets', group: :development
etc....
```

Comment: which gem do you use here?

Comment: Did you add this gem to `Gemfile` and run `bundle install`?

Comment: did you restart the rails server after running bundle install?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the latest version of activerecord-reputation-system gem which supports Rails 4.

Update your Gemfile: `gem 'activerecord-reputation-system'`